# How to get updated value of table sent from C++ to Lua function?

Tags: c++, arrays, lua, reference, lua-table

I'm trying to pass a float vector from C++ function to Lua function as a table parameter and then get the updated value of the vector after the Lua function call.

Here's the simple example code.

```
void myFunc(lua_State *L, std::vector<float> &vec) {

    lua_getglobal(L, "myFunc");
    lua_newtable(L);

    for (size_t i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i) {

        lua_pushinteger(L, i+1);
        lua_pushnumber(L, vec[i]);
        lua_settable(L, -3);
    }
    if (lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0) != 0) {

        std::cout << "Error : Failed to call myFunc" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And then I can call this function as the following.

```
std::vector<float> vec = {1,2,3,4,5}; //an array that will be sent to Lua as table
    myFunc(L, vec); //call "myFunc" function in Lua and pass the array as an argument

    /* <Lua function which will be called>
     function myFunc(t)
        for i=1, #t do
            t[i] = t[i] * 2
        end
     end
     */

    //how to update elements of "vec" here so it now becomes {2,4,6,8,10}?
```

As I commented in the code, I would like to update the elements of `vector<float> vec` after calling the Lua function.

Is it possible to pass the array to Lua function as a reference? (like how it works in C++ functions)

If not, is it possible to get the values of Lua table(t) so I can write them back to the float vector in C++ after calling the function?

Thanks!

Comment: You have two options: (1) Have another C++ function to which you pass the updated table from Lua, which then updates the vector.  (2) Pass the vector as userdata to Lua with a metatable which has overloaded `__len` and `__index` metamethods which call C++ functions which update the vector inside the userdata inplace (this comes closest to “pass an array by reference to Lua”).

Comment: After `lua_pcall` you should insert another loop `for (size_t i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i)` to update the vector (a loop similar to the loop before `lua_pcall`)

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. I think I found one solution. I changed `lua_pcall` to `lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0)` so it returns a table. and then added the following code after it.

`for (size_t i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i) {
        lua_pushinteger(L, i+1);
        lua_gettable(L, -2);
        vec[i] = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }`
Is this similar to your option (1)? I wonder if there's any faster solution than this since it will be used to process audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Converting std::vector to and from Lua table

As discussed [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172084) it might be desirable to convert the function arguments from `std::vector<float>` to Lua tables and the return value from Lua table to `std::vector<float>`.  The advantage of this is that it is completely transparent at the Lua end.

The function `as_table` creates a new table from a pair of iterators, `from_table` converts from a Lua table on top of the stack to a pair of iterators.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <lua.hpp>

template <typename T, typename U>
void as_table(lua_State* L, T begin, U end) {
    lua_newtable(L);
    for (size_t i = 0; begin != end; ++begin, ++i) {
        lua_pushinteger(L, i + 1);
        lua_pushnumber(L, *begin);
        lua_settable(L, -3);
    }
}

template <typename T, typename U>
void from_table(lua_State* L, T begin, U end) {
    assert(lua_istable(L,-1));
    for (size_t i = 0; begin != end; ++begin, ++i) {
        lua_pushinteger(L, i + 1);
        lua_gettable(L, -2);
        *begin = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <script.lua>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    if (luaL_dofile(L, argv[1]) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "lua_dofile failed: " << lua_tostring(L, -1) << '\n';
        lua_close(L);
        return 1;
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "perform");

    std::vector<float> iv(2000, 1);
    std::vector<float> ov(2000, 2);

    as_table(L, iv.begin(), iv.end());
    as_table(L, ov.begin(), ov.end());

    if (lua_pcall(L, 2, 1, 0) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "lua_pcall failed: " << lua_tostring(L, -1)
                  << '\n';
        lua_close(L);
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<float> w(2000);
    from_table(L, w.begin(), w.end());

    assert(std::all_of(w.begin(), w.end(),
                       [](float p) { return p == 3.0f; }));
}
```

Here is the little Lua script which is to be used with the testcase above.

```
function perform(v1,v2)
    local n = math.min(#v1,#v2)
    local v = {}
    for i = 1,n do
        v[i] = v1[i] + v2[i]
    end
    return v
end
```

## std::vector as userdata

Pushing the vector as a table is advantageous if most of the data manipulation is done on the Lua end, because Lua tables are actually pretty fast.  If, however, most of the computations were done on the C++ end and the Lua end would only pass around the data between functions implemented in C++ this approach would add a large overhead, because we'd spend lots of time converting back and forth between Lua tables and `std::vector`.  To this end, Lua provides **userdata**, a method to wrap C/C++ datastructures in such a way that they apprear as native Lua datatypes.  The downside is, that when offering functions to inspect userdata from Lua, those are usually slow, because arguments have to be checked repeatedly and multiple nested functions have to be called.  Combine this with metatables to have syntactic sugar for array access and length operations and you will find yourself in performance hell.

That said, I have constructed an example of pushing the vector as userdata and set its metatable.  This process is also described in the chapter [28.1 – Userdata](https://www.lua.org/pil/28.1.html) in the book “Programming in Lua” (read it!).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <lua.hpp>

std::vector<float>& checkvector(lua_State *L, int index) {
    std::vector<float> *v = *static_cast<std::vector<float> **>(
        luaL_checkudata(L, index, "std::vector<float>"));
    luaL_argcheck(L, v != nullptr, index, "invalid pointer");
    return *v;
}

static int newvector(lua_State *L) {
    size_t size = luaL_checkinteger(L, 1);
    luaL_argcheck(L, size >= 0, 1, "invalid size");
    *static_cast<std::vector<float> **>(lua_newuserdata(
        L, sizeof(std::vector<float> *))) = new std::vector<float>(size);

    luaL_getmetatable(L, "std::vector<float>");
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    return 1;
}

void pushvector(lua_State *L, std::vector<float> const &v) {
    std::vector<float> *udata = new std::vector<float>();
    *udata = v;
    *static_cast<std::vector<float> **>(lua_newuserdata(
        L, sizeof(std::vector<float> *))) = udata;

    luaL_getmetatable(L, "std::vector<float>");
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
}

static int deletevector(lua_State *L) {
    delete &checkvector(L, 1);
    return 0;
}

static int setvector(lua_State *L) {
    std::vector<float> &v = checkvector(L, 1);
    size_t index = luaL_checkinteger(L, 2) - 1;
    luaL_argcheck(L, index < v.size(), 2, "index out of range");
    luaL_argcheck(L, lua_isnumber(L, 3), 3, "not a number");
    float record = lua_tonumber(L, 3);

    v.at(index) = record;

    return 0;
}

static int getvector(lua_State *L) {
    std::vector<float> &v = checkvector(L, 1);
    size_t index = luaL_checkinteger(L, 2) - 1;
    luaL_argcheck(L, index < v.size(), 2, "index out of range");

    lua_pushnumber(L, v.at(index));

    return 1;
}

static int getsize(lua_State *L) {
    std::vector<float> &v = checkvector(L, 1);

    lua_pushinteger(L, v.size());

    return 1;
}

static int vectortostring(lua_State *L) {
    std::vector<float> &v = checkvector(L, 1);

    lua_pushfstring(L, "std::vector<float>(%d)", v.size());

    return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg vector_float_lib[] = {
    {"new", newvector},
    {nullptr, nullptr} // sentinel
};

static const struct luaL_Reg vector_float_meta[] = {
    {"__tostring", vectortostring},
    {"__newindex", setvector},
    {"__index", getvector},
    {"__len", getsize},
    {"__gc", deletevector},
    {nullptr, nullptr} // sentinel
};

int luaopen_vector_float(lua_State *L) {
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "std::vector<float>");
    luaL_setfuncs(L, vector_float_meta, 0);
    luaL_newlib(L, vector_float_lib);
    return 1;
}


static int send_vector(lua_State *L) {
    std::vector<float> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    pushvector(L,v);
    return 1;
}

static int retrieve_vector(lua_State *L) {
    std::vector<float> &v = checkvector(L, 1);
    for (auto const &p : v) {
        std::cout << p << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    luaL_requiref(L, "vector", luaopen_vector_float, 1);
    lua_pop(L, 1);

    lua_pushcfunction(L,send_vector);
    lua_setglobal(L,"send_vector");

    lua_pushcfunction(L,retrieve_vector);
    lua_setglobal(L,"retrieve_vector");

    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <script.lua>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    luaL_dofile(L, argv[1]);

    lua_close(L);
}
```

This can execute the following Lua script

```
local v = send_vector()
for i = 1,#v do
    v[i] = 2*v[i]
end
retrieve_vector(v)
```

---

Given a global function `transform_vector`, e.g.

```
function transform_vector(v)
    for i = 1,#v do
        v[i] = 2*v[i]
    end
    return v
end
```

one can call this function with a vector argument and retrieve a vector result just like with any other Lua function.

```
std::vector<float> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
lua_getglobal(L,"transform_vector");
pushvector(L,v);
if (lua_pcall(L,1,1,0) != 0) {
    // handle error
}
std::vector<float> w = checkvector(L, -1);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it works very well. However, what I would like to do is pass `vector<float>`(e.g. {1,2,3,4,5}) as an argument from C++ to Lua function and then retrieve the modified data (e.g. {2,4,6,8,10}) so I can use it again in C++. I don't understand how this can be done with your solution.

Comment: @ZackLee See the updated answer.  I also tried pushing a reference to a vector onto the Lua stack but that does not play nicely with GC.  Also the reference on the C++ side might go dangling which would blow up your program.  So better push onto the stack by value.  I pushed the vector as the return value of a function but of course you can also push it as a global.

Comment: Thank you for the update and explanation. Is it not possible to send the vector as an argument like how I wrote in my post? (please find `function myFunc(t)`).
I'm trying to make the Lua code as simple and efficient as possible. So I would like to send vector as a table argument and process `retrieve_vector()` in C++ as well if possible. I also wonder if your solution will be more efficient than mine. (Please find my comment)

Comment: @ZackLee The userdata approach is more efficient than pushing every single element into a table because it does not have to copy so much data.  You can call the function like any other Lua function.  I will add an example.

Comment: @ZackLee Example added.  However, I recommend the “functional programming” approach here.  Pass data around as arguments to functions and return values from functions.  Don't hold on to the data and don't try to encapsulate state.  This way your program will remain flexible because functions can be composed.

Comment: Hey, this is exactly what I want. thank you so much for your example and explanation. I would like to give you a reward.

Comment: @ZackLee You can start a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to reward an existing answer with extra points, but I'm totally fine with you saying thanks :)

Comment: It's so weird I still not see the bounty button. I have 75 points which I think is enough to give 50. Please wait until I figure this out.

Comment: @ZackLee You can go to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges and see whether the privilege has been unlocked.  There is usually a delay between hitting the mark and being awarded the privilege.

Comment: Sir, Could you please have a look at my question which I posted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854346/how-to-get-multiple-returned-tables-from-lua-function

Answer (score 0):

Just for future references, I (try to) enhance Henri's code, put a function to send 2d arrays form C to lua and put some comments. If helps anyone...

```
#define SOL_ALL_SAFETIES_ON 1
#include <sol/sol.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sol/assert.hpp>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename U>
void as_table(lua_State* L, T begin, U end, char *tablename) {
    lua_newtable(L);
    for(int i=0; begin!=end; ++begin, i++) {
        lua_pushnumber(L, i);
        lua_pushnumber(L, *begin);
        lua_rawset(L, -3);
    }
    lua_setglobal(L, tablename);
}

template <typename T, typename U>
void from_table(lua_State* L, T begin, U end) {
    assert(lua_istable(L,-1));
    for (size_t i = 0; begin != end; ++begin, ++i) {
        lua_pushinteger(L, i);
        lua_gettable(L, -2);
        *begin = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void as_2Darray(lua_State *L, T **arr, int n0, int n1) {
    lua_newtable(L);
    for (int i=0; i<n0; i++) {
        lua_pushnumber(L, i);
        lua_newtable(L);
        for (int j=0; j<n1; j++) {
            lua_pushnumber(L, j);
            lua_pushnumber(L, arr[i][j]);
            lua_rawset(L, -3);
        }
        lua_rawset(L, -3);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /**
    Full example of setting and getting variables from and to Lua/C++
    */

    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    ///Sending x=11 to Lua
    lua_pushnumber(L, 11);
    lua_setglobal(L, "x");

    ///Sending a vector to Lua
    vector<double> cvec(10, 1222); //vector with some noise
    cvec[0] = 333;
    cvec[1] = 444;
    cvec[9] = 999;
    as_table(L, cvec.begin(), cvec.end(), "vetor");


    /**
    For future reference: Lua works based on something like a "stack pattern" (I know that there should be a nicer name, just be kind, ok?).
    Simplifying a lot: we push stuff and then execute commands based on what is on the stack.
    More info:
    https://www.lua.org/pil/24.2.1.html
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4l5HdmPoynw
    https://github.com/tylerneylon/lua_api_demo

    Eg: the following 4 lines:
    */
    ///Sending an array foo={47, 80} to Lua
    lua_newtable(L);        // put a table on the stack
    lua_pushnumber(L, 0);   // put the number "0" on the stack
    lua_pushnumber(L, 47);  // put the number "47" on the stack
    lua_rawset(L, -3);      // put the value of stack[-1] at index identified on stack[-2] on the table of stack [-3]
                            // i.e., index=0 -> value = 47

    lua_pushnumber(L, 1); //index
    lua_pushnumber(L, 80); //value
    lua_rawset(L, -3);

    lua_setglobal(L, "foo");   //Label the table at stack[-1] as foo

    ///Execute some code
    luaL_dostring(L, "x=15\nprint(x)\nprint(foo[0])\nprint(vetor[0])\nfoo[0] = 387\nprint(foo[0])");

    ///Get value of x
    lua_getglobal(L,"x");
    double x = (double)lua_tonumber(L, -1);

    cout << "x from lua: " << x << endl;

    ///Get an element from array foo
    lua_getglobal(L, "foo");
    lua_pushinteger(L, 0);
    lua_gettable(L, -2);
    cout << "foo[0] = " << lua_tonumber(L, -1) << endl;

    ///Get the vector
    vector<double> luavec(10, 2);
    lua_getglobal(L, "vetor");
    from_table(L, luavec.begin(), luavec.end());

    int a = 0;
    for(auto i:luavec) {
        cout << a<<".luavec: " << i << endl;
        a++;
    }

    double **alpha = new double*[2];
    alpha[0] = new double[3];
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        alpha[0][i] = i+1;
    }
    alpha[1] = new double[3];
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        alpha[1][i] = i+10;
    }

    as_2Darray(L, alpha, 2, 3);
    lua_setglobal(L, "twod");

    luaL_dostring(L, "print('twod:',twod[0][0], twod[1][0], twod[0][1])");
}
```